# Unknown houseplant -- what is the one on the LEFT?

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care

That's pretty much it. I need to care for this unknown plant. What is it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The upright habit of this plant indicates that it is a variegated Peperomia obtusifolia.  Peperomias have rather thick leaves since they use the leaves as water storage, in contrast to other thinner leaved species which do not store moisture in the leaves. You can quickly test thick from thin leaves by attempting to bend a leaf - if it feels rubbery then it is likely a Peperomia.

Comment: Colin is correct, so I deleted my answer.  I had a feeling something was wrong about the pothos theory.